# How to call non-static Java methods from C++ code (android)?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Please help to call java void method(non static) from C++, It simple sdl2 android project . I'am trynig many times but can't make it works:-(.  CallVoidMethod always crashes.

C++ code:

```
JNIEnv* Android_JNI_GetEnv(void) {
    JNIEnv *env;
    int status = mJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
    if(status < 0) {
        LOGE("failed to attach current thread");
        return 0;
    }

    return env;
}

int Android_JNI_SetupThread(void) {

    JNIEnv *env = Android_JNI_GetEnv();
    pthread_setspecific(mThreadKey, (void*) env);
    return 1;
}   

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    mJavaVM = vm;
    LOGI("JNI_OnLoad called");
    if (mJavaVM->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
        LOGE("Failed to get the environment using GetEnv()");
        return -1;
    }
        Android_JNI_SetupThread();


    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}


void B_Init(JNIEnv* mEnv, jclass cls, jobject obj)
{
    Android_JNI_SetupThread();

    mActivityClass = (jclass)mEnv->NewGlobalRef(cls);

}


extern "C" void Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInitB(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject obj)
{
    /* This interface could expand with ABI negotiation, calbacks, etc. */
    B_Init(env, cls, obj);

}

    void Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeDemoInit()
    {

    JNIEnv* env = Android_JNI_GetEnv();

    jclass cls;

    jmethodID mid;

    cls =  env->FindClass("org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity");

    mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "displayInterstitial2", "()V");

    **env->CallVoidMethod(cls, mid2);**

    } 
}
```

Java code(org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity):

```
/**
    SDL Activity
**/
public class SDLActivity extends Activity {


public void displayInterstitial2() {

            some code;

    }

}
```

I'm trying next to simplify code

C++ code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeinitB(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    jclass clz =  env->GetObjectClass(obj);  // instead of FindClass
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clz, "displayInterstitial2", "()V");
   // if(!mid) return;  // method does not exist, should write some logs
   env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid); 
}
```

and get error:
No implementation for native Lorg/libsdl/app/SDLActivity;.nativeInitB:()V

Comment: I can see your method name is `displayInterstitial` and you call `displayInterstitial2` from C++. Any explanation for that?

Comment: Sorry in real code it's displayInterstitial2 in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call native method from your activity, you can try this way:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeDemoInit(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj){
   jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);  // instead of FindClass
   jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "displayInterstitial2", "()V");
   if(!mid) return;  // method does not exist, should write some logs
   (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mid);
}
```

in Activity class:

```
 public void displayInterstitial2(){
    Log.d("call displayInterstitial2");
 }

 public native void nativeDemoInit();
```

Reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548939/719212) and [this](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/java-native-interface)

Comment: GetMethodID gives me an error can find method in class Ljava/lang/CLass, but i call nativeDemoInit in SDLActivity. and displayInterstitial2 in SDLActivity.

Comment: I updated my answer with workable code. You can try it

Comment: after trying this I have an error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.nativeDemoInit:()V

Comment: Please check your package for correction. **Make sure your SDLActivity is in `org.libsdl.app` package**. If still not work, please update your full source code (include package and method prototype)