# Program crashes when I call CallVoidMethodA

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I try to call several non-static java methods from c. I've checked if any of the object, method or env variables are null, none of them are. The program works well when I use static methods instead of non-static

```
JavaVM *jvm;
jobject g_obj;
jmethodID g_mid;

void func(){
  jclass DTK_ANPR_Test;
  jmethodID dtk_anpr;
  DTK_ANPR_Test = (*env)->FindClass(env, "DTKANPRTest");
  g_mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, DTK_ANPR_Test, "anpr", "(I)V");
  jobject obj = (*env)->NewObjectA(env, DTK_ANPR_Test, g_mid, val);
  g_obj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, DTK_ANPR_Test);

}
```

And I call `(*env)->CallVoidMethodA(env, g_obj, g_mid, val);`
  from same method or another method, the program crashes at that point. Is it a problem with object or something else ?

P.S. I use `AttachCurrentThread` and `DetachCurrentThread` to call the method another time from native code

P.S. There is another similar thread, which didn't solve my problem:
[JNI crashes when calling CallVoidMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530821/jni-crashes-when-calling-callvoidmethod)

Comment: How and where is `val` set up?

Comment: val is setup using:  jvalue *val=(jvalue *)malloc(sizeof(jvalue));
                val->i=(jint *)malloc(sizeof(jint));
                       (val->i)=(jint)k;// k is provided as parameter

Answer (score 0):

To return the constructor function of a class from `GetMethodId`, pass `<init>` as the method name, not the class name. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html):

> jobject NewObjectA(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
>   jmethodID methodID, const jvalue *args);
>
> Constructs a new Java object. The method ID indicates which constructor method to invoke. This ID must be obtained by calling GetMethodID() with `<init>` as the method name and void (V) as the return type.

So change the code to:

```
g_mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, DTK_ANPR_Test, "<init>", "(I)V");
```

Also, you aren't saving a reference to the object you are creating with `NewObjectA`. Change your code to this:

```
g_obj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, obj);
```

The reason your code was working for static methods is that the class object is used rather than a object instance when calling a static method.

Comment: I've added a constructor methodID to the NewObject, and another global method for caching the 'anpr' method ID (the method which I wish to call from native code). However the problem still persists

Comment: You aren't saving a reference to the object you are creating. Try g_obj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, obj);

Comment: Yes, I did this as well before

Comment: jmethodID dtk_constructor=(*env)->GetMethodID(env, DTK_ANPR_Test, "anpr", "()V");   jobject obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, DTK_ANPR_Test, dtk_constructor);    g_obj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, obj);   The program crashes when I create the local object

Comment: pass "<init>" not "anpr" to GetMethodID

Comment: It did work, thank you :) There are other problems when I was running the java method from different parallel threads though

Comment: The code you have posted is not related to threading so I think that is a separate issue.

Comment: I use invoke_method to CallVoidMethodA which has the code of attaching it to a thread as well. This invoke_method works well when I call it any number of times. But it executes the first time and ceases to print anymore statements when I use invoke_method inside a FreeRTOS scheduler. But I could observe that the code is running still although nothing is being printed. Using fflush() has no major improvement

Comment: None of that is mentioned in your original question, which was about getting a crash on CallVoidMethodA after creating an object. Start a new question if you want help with your threading issues.